# How to pinvoke unicode version of SHGetFileInfo (c#)?

Tags: c#, unicode, pinvoke

I tried this:

```
public struct SHFILEINFOW
            {
                public IntPtr hIcon;
                public int iIcon;
                public uint dwAttributes;
                [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 260 * 2)]
                public string szDisplayName;
                [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 80 * 2)]
                public string szTypeName;
            }
    [DllImport("shell32.dll")]
            public static extern IntPtr SHGetFileInfoW(IntPtr pIDL, uint dwFileAttributes, out SHFILEINFOW psfi, uint cbFileInfo, SHGFI uFlags);
    String DisplayName = shInfoW.szDisplayName;
```

But DisplayName contain only the first char

Comment: Does http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/shell32/SHGetFileInfo.html not work for you for some reason?

Comment: I'll need to think about the actual problem; however, I would explicitly add a StructLayout attribute to make your structure layout sequential.

Comment: SHGetFileInfo return ????????? for folder named เอาขึ้นมาทามม้ายยย

Comment: Hey Irwan, take a look at that structure in the debugger and make sure it's truly returning one character and not just looking like it's one character because the second byte is zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
   [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 260 * 2)]
```

`ByValTStr` means "same as the class or structure".  But you didn't specify the CharSet attribute for the structure.  It defaults to CharSet.Ansi so the string is getting marshaled as though it was a 8-bit character string.  Since the real string is Unicode, you'll indeed get very high odds for only getting the first character.  Fix:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public struct SHFILEINFOW {
   // etc...
}
```

Comment: +1. Do you know why `[DllImport("shell32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]`/ `[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]` as suggested on http://pinvoke.net did not work for OP?

Comment: The CharSet for the [DllImport] determines whether SHGetFileInfoW or SHGetFileInfoA is called.  After the call completes, the pinvoke marshaller goes to work converting the native structure.  Guided by the CharSet attribute on the struct.

Comment: @Alex: sorry, I meant SHGetFileInfo on my original code. The code on that page works too